# running a server side exe from an asp page

Tags: asp-classic

i have a classic asp page that calls an exe that does some complex processes. I want the asp page to wait until the exe completes processing. I tried shell. no luck. any solution?

-Vivek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AspExec used to be a popular tool, but it doesn't seem like the [company](http://www.serverobjects.com/products.html) sells it anymore. You can still find it [here](http://www.nodevice.com/dll/ASPEXEC_DLL/item1931.html) for download. See this [article](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-execute-a-dos-command/batch-file/exe-from-asp.html) for using it, as well as other options.